# Wave equation with boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation

Given the wave equation $u_{xx}=\frac{1}{v^2}u_{tt}$ (for $v=const$) with the boundary condition $u(0,t)=0$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$. There exists a simply proof that $u=u(x,t)$ must be:
$$u(x,t)=f(x+vt)-f(x-vt)\ ?$$
I only know to prove that (without the boundary condition) $u(x,t)=f(x+vt)+g(x-vt)$ for some $f,g$ smooth functions.

Comment: One boundary condition alone is not enough to get a unique solution. Plus, it wouldn't be a solution of that form. There's something wrong with the question.

Answer (score 2):

Impose the boundary condition on $u(x,t)=f(x+v\,t)+g(x-v\,t)$ to get
$$
f(v\,t)+g(-v\,t)=0.
$$
Letting $v\,t=z$ we see that
$$
g(z)=-f(-z).
$$